# Как подключиться к устройству по uart через эмулятор терминала linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, uart

Есть устройство с linux, к нему можно подключиться по uart и работать из терминала. Есть персональный компьютер с linux, дистрибутив ubuntu, он подключается к устройству через адаптер usb-uart. Как можно подключить эмулятор терминала персонального компьютера к устройству без использования сторонних утилит, таких как minicom?

Comment: А чем не устраивают minicom, pcomm, pytty и т.д.? Imho gnome-terminal, xterm и т.п. не предусматривают подключения к device (впрочем, у xterm есть ключ -Snn, но он для подключения к slave-части pty и я не представляю, как воткнуть туда any-device) / Впрочем, читать и писать в такой device можно (немного неудобно, но можно) парой обычных cat-ов (или cat для чтения, а echo "..." >> device для записи туда)

Comment: @avp, при работе через эти программы возникают проблемы с автодополнением команд, иногда возникают непредсказуемые эффекты при вставке текста или его редактирования из-за чего можно запустить неверную команду, в результате приходится все команды вводить полностью, что неудобно.

Comment: @Максим, а банальный `screen /dev/ttyS0 9600` уже пробовал?